# Concatenation - First Name and Last Name Same Column (Oracle SQL)

Tags: join, count, concatenation

Completely new to Oracle SQL, with that being said:

Trying to display author first and last name in the same column as "Author" along with the number of books written by that author (results in ascending order by author first name).

```
SELECT AUTHOR.FNAME || ' ' || AUTHOR.LNAME AS "Author",
COUNT(BOOKAUTHOR.AUTHORID) AS "Books written"
FROM BOOKS
INNER JOIN BOOKAUTHOR ON BOOKS.ISBN = BOOKAUTHOR.ISBN
INNER JOIN AUTHOR ON BOOKAUTHOR.AuthorID = AUTHOR.AuthorID
ORDER BY AUTHOR.FNAME ASC
```

Concatenation doesn't seem to be working and having issues with the overall query.

Here are the tables that relate:

**Books**: ISBN, TITLE

**Author**: AUTHORID, LNAME, FNAME

**BookAuthor**: ISBN, AUTHORID

Even when I try and do a simple concatenation with just using SELECT and FROM it does not show any results.

Like for example:

```
SELECT FNAME || ' ' || LNAME "AUTHOR NAME"
FROM AUTHOR
```

Comment: are you sure there are any rows in your author table? Did you try the second query with `AS`

Comment: Actually the second query works now.  It seems after running for a while my oracle stops giving back any results for a query.  I have to restart it and then the query will work.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(CONCAT(AUTHOR.FNAME, ' '),
      AUTHOR.LNAME) AS "AUTHOR" 
COUNT(BOOKAUTHOR.AUTHORID) AS "Books written"
FROM BOOKS
INNER JOIN BOOKAUTHOR ON BOOKS.ISBN = BOOKAUTHOR.ISBN
INNER JOIN AUTHOR ON BOOKAUTHOR.AuthorID = AUTHOR.AuthorID
ORDER BY AUTHOR.FNAME ASC
```